# How does action server and controllers interact

Tags: ros

How does action server and controllers interact. For example action client sends trajectory msgs to action server, than how does action server sends the same trajectory msgs to joint trajectory controller, and why to use action interface between the controller and action client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `joint_trajectory_controller` instantiates an action server. The choice of actionlib for this controller comes naturally from the nature of the the task. A client sends a trajectory to the controller, which will then play it until it is done or canceled.

Since ROS interfaces are not real-time-safe, the action server is typically separated from the real-time thread that is in charge of playing the current trajectory on the actual hardware, but both the real-time part and the action server run in the same process.